# Python - appending to class-level lists in derived class definitions

Tags: python, class-variables

```
class A (object):
    keywords = ('one', 'two', 'three')

class B (A):
    keywords = A.keywords + ('four', 'five', 'six')
```

Is there any way to change `A.keywords` to `<thing B derives from>.keywords`, sort of like `super()`, but pre-`__init__/self`? I don't like repeating class names in definitions.

Usage:

```
>>> A.keywords
('one', 'two', 'three')
>>> B.keywords
('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can. Write a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) that checks the class's bases for an attribute with the same name and add the passed attributes to its value.

```
class parentplus(object):
    def __init__(self, name, current):
        self.name = name
        self.value = current

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # Find the attribute in self.name in instance's bases
        # Implementation left as an exercise for the reader

class A(object):
    keywords = ('one', 'two', 'three')

class B(A):
    keywords = parentplus('keywords', ('four', 'five', 'six'))
```

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't yet thought of turning to an even more external place for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the __bases__ attr to find the base class(es) whenever you've already init'ed your class. Otherwise you need to change approach as B is not aware of its parents.

```
class A (object):
    keywords = ('one', 'two', 'three')

class B (A):
    def __init__(self):
        keywords = self.__bases__[0].keywords + ('four', 'five', 'six')
```

Comment: The point of the question was how to do it at class definition time.

Comment: @GaryFixler afg is correct, use Ignatio method, mine simply wont work at base level.

Comment: Understood. And yes, I need this at the class level, pre-instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use metaclass :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_cls = super(Meta,cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if hasattr(new_cls, 'keywords'):
            new_cls.keywords += ('1','2')
        return new_cls

class B(object):
    keywords = ('0',)
    __metaclass__= Meta

def main():
    print B().keywords

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: While this is the only way I see to do it without calling any classes by name, it seems out of proportion to the problem.

Comment: True, agf. It's great info, but I'm looking for a tiny solution, like super().keywords + keywords. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround-style solution working for me without additional classes and defs.

```
class BaseModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    _readonly_fields = readonly_fields = ('created_by', 'date_add', 'date_upd', 'deleted')
```

and when subclassing

```
class PayerInline(BaseTabularInline):
    exclude = BaseTabularInline._exclude + ('details',)
```

Hope this helps.